# Facebook Open Graph - friends_actions:{app_namespace} error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

According to [this post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/permissions/), friend activities on an application can be retrieved when requesting `friends_actions:{app_namespace}` permssion.

However, when I request that permission, the permission does not appear on the auth dialogue. Does anyone get this error?

Comment: Another question would be, whats the Open Graph query structure to access friend activities?

Answer (score 3):

This works fine for me, using pinterest as an example:

Request `friends_actions:pinterestapp` permission in the auth dialog and verify it's been granted with a call to `/me/permissions`:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "installed": 1, 
      "read_stream": 1, 
      //Snipped a bunch of irrelevant actions
      "user_actions:pinterestapp": 1, 
      "friends_actions:pinterestapp": 1, 
    }
  ]
}
```

Call `/[friend who uses pinterest's ID]/pinterestapp:pin`

Format of the response is:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "10100800772217878", 
      "from": {
        "id": "REMOVED ID", 
        "name": "REMOVED NAME"
      }, 
      "start_time": "2012-06-13T11:08:37+0000", 
      "end_time": "2012-06-13T11:08:37+0000", 
      "publish_time": "2012-06-13T11:08:37+0000", 
      "application": {
        "id": "274266067164", 
        "name": "Pinterest "
      }, 
      "data": {
        "pin": {
          "id": "10150834999992132", 
          "url": "http://pinterest.com/pin/REMOVED_ID/?timeline=1", 
          "type": "pinterestapp:pin", 
          "title": "Runway"
        }
      }, 
      "likes": {
        "count": 0
      }, 
      "comments": {
        "count": 0
      }
    }, 
//SNIP
```

For multiple friends you can call `/pinterestapp:pin?ids=<CSV LIST OF USER IDS OF FRIENDS>`

Comment: How can the friends_actions:pinterestapp permission be requested from The New Auth Dialog?

Comment: `&scope=friends_actions:pinterestapp` in your call to the dialog - i don't think you can add this to the typeahead for the authenticated referrals settings though

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the CSV list of friend IDs? ie. can we get a list of all friends who took a particular action on an Open Graph object?

Comment: Not that i can see, but you can easily build the CSV list from a call to `/me/friends` or an FQL query